# How to set same heights for bootstrap tabs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple tabs menu which also contains input controls.

[image]

[image]

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="">
        <a>tab4</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a><input value="tab5"/></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

After I added the input, now the tabs have some inconsistences regarding the styling. How can I set the same heights for tabs ?

Here is the jsfiddle : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fm2dupb/)

Comment: Can you build a jsfiddle please?

Comment: They have the same height in your jsfiddle. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @EdisonBiba, try to hover the tab4 and you will see the inconsistence. Then you could mark the tab4 as active one.

Comment: Playng with your fiddle i'll add this _border:none;padding:0;_ to input and works. So the issue i think it is with your input will change the heigth of the li. try to set a fixed height to the li element

Comment: @Sfili_81, yes, it works. Please add it as an answer in order to vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2hkqa3w/1/) with working example

The problem here is because input has border and it increases the height of the input tab.

You can set the height of your other tab greater than input.

```
.nav li > a {
    line-height: 26px
}

.nav li > a input{
    line-height: 20px
}
```

So depending on your input height you want just add 6 more pixels to other tabs

You can also use flex to do this dynamically so giving flex to tabs would work but you need to check how to works with your other components.

```
.nav.nav-tabs, .nav.nav-tabs > li{
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you can play with `input height`.

```
.nav li.active input {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Choose max-size of panel */

.panel--sections {
  max-width: 800px;
}


/* Give some top and bottom padding for the columns */

.col-sm-6 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}


/* Give col-left a border at bottom if on mobile */

.col-left {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Give col-left a border on right if on bigger screen */
  .col-left {
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.nav li.active input {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="">
    <a>tab4</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a><input value="tab5" /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will cause a problem when user change tabs because input height will change.

Comment: i didn't check that scenario but you are right this can be done with line-height as well.

Comment: You just need to remove .active class in your selector :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set a fixed height, you can make both your ul and li flex (below adds a flex-tabs class to the nav-tabs ul):

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");

body {
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Choose max-size of panel */
.panel--sections {
  max-width: 800px;
}

/* Give some top and bottom padding for the columns */
.col-sm-6 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Give col-left a border at bottom if on mobile */
.col-left {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;

}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* Give col-left a border on right if on bigger screen */
  .col-left {
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.flex-tabs,
.flex-tabs li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="">
    <a>tab4</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a><input value="tab5" /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```